# Spring reactive poor performance on high load

Tags: spring-boot, performance, blocking

I have a spring boot webflux application which by default uses netty.
One of the business requirements that we have mandates that requests should time out within 2 seconds.

When very few requests are sent to the app, everything is fine but when the request load is increased (Like over 40 or 50 concurrent per second by Jmeter) sometimes all of them time out due to each taking longer than the 2-second threshold.

I have spent a long time reading things online and looking into what could be causing this issue but with no success. When requests are sent concurrently most end up taking a long time and the problematic part is where an external HTTTP request is made to other microservice. All my tests are local and I have tested the microservices and they seem fast enough to handle a big load so the microservices themselves are not the issue.

I know that netty uses event loop and does not create a thread per request.
I believe there are likely synchronous tasks that are blocking those few netty threads. For this reason I have done massive refactoring and have ".publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())" or ".subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())" in the Mono reactive chains. After the refactoring Most of the operations seem to be running on elastic threads and not the "reactor-http-nio-x" (According to the logs) but doing so has not helped the main issue and the problem still exists.

It will be a huge help if someone could direct me to what I should be doing. At this point, I have no more improvements to make, and think I might have been looking at this the wrong way and my approach has not been correct.

I have not attached any code sine the application is big and I do not still know where the actual problem lies.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: We had the similar issues in production as well and it turned out that the main cause was due to the network issues which caused random hick ups causing some service call to take longer than usual.
When I had posted this question this was based on local testing with everything running locally. So short answer is that I have not found any solution. 
I might try ZZ 5's suggestion on avoiding using webClient.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. I've didn't find the root cause of this, but when I switched from `WebClient` to `RestTemplate` with dedicated thread pool per client (external service) then the problem was solved. I've run a blockhound to find if I block somewhere in the stream, but it didn't find anything. I've also tried deploying my application with increased number of NIO worker thread pool (by default it's equal to cores number) and there was some improvement, but after all `RestTemplate` yielded the best performance. So I'm still on Webflux stack, but I don't use `WebClient` anymore and the performance on high load is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have had this issue on local environment as well when everything runs locally but upon increasing the load some local service call take a long time. I have not tried to see how it would perform without using webClient however.